# Complex edge conditions on geo-edges

Tags: database, graph, dijkstra

Spatial graph databases are capable to find a shortest path from the node A to the node B. Are there any DB which allows complex conditions on nodes and edges between them?

For example:

- The node is closed between 01:00 - 06:00 UTC
- The edge is available only on weekends
- The edge is available if we passed the node X and going to the node Y
- The edge is not available in winter
- The node is temporarily disabled
- The polygon closes all edges intersecting it
- etc

Are there any DBs which allows such geo-restrictions?

Say we can call some function when considering the edge as a candidate?

Comment: 'spatial graph databases' is a bit vague here. but e.g. in *pgRouting* for *PostgreSQL (+ PostGIS)*, basically all routing functions require the edges to be included passed in as **(SQL expression) strings**; this allows for highly dynamic network definitions when combined with the base table/node table attributes.

Comment: So it's possible with PostgreSQL, right?

Comment: with the right set of attributes it certainly should. note that there is no 'out-of-the-box' solution for any of your examples implemented in *pgRouting*; but for each call to, say, `pgr_dijkstra` you need to provide the function with a set of edges to route on via an SQL expression, so you can filter your routing graph highly flexible (and dynamically when wrapped within a custom function). I suggest to investigate since it's one of the most sophistocated routing frameworks for FOSS RDBMS.